# Relation I found: $ (\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{z(r)}{r})\times \int_0^\infty f(x) dx = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=0}^{n} f(k_ih)h$

Tags: integration, combinatorics, number-theory, limits

I was fiddling with some maths and came up with an interesting relationship:

$$ (\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{z(r)}{r})\times \int_0^\infty f(x) dx = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(k_ih)h$$

This is true for any $ f(x) $ which converges and the relation between $ k_i $ and $ z(r) $ are:

$$ J(x) =\sum_{i=1}^\infty z(i) x^i $$

and

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty J(x^r) = \sum_{i=1}^n x^{k_i}$$

where $ k_i $ must be equal to an integer greater than $ 0 $ and must be such that if $ k_i = k_j $ implies $ i= j $.

An implication of restricting $ k_i $ to an integer greater than $ 0 $ is that even $ z(r) $ must belong to the integers. Also, n is the number of $k_i $. Besides that there are no other constraints on $ k_i , f(x), z(r)$  Is such a relationship already existing? If not can someone tell if this work can be applied anywhere? (Please comment if you do not understand anything or want me to make something more elaborate)EDIT: I believe the above relation can also be modified as:

$$ (\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{z(r)}{r})\times \int_0^\infty f(x, s) dx = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(k_ih,s)h$$

Where $ s $ is a variable.

Comment: Your definition for $J(x)$ only makes sense for $|x|<1$, right? How else can you guarantee the sum is convergent? And even with that assumption, how can you guarantee that the latter sum converges? Lastly how can you guarantee that latter sum is the sum of (finitely many) powers of $x$?

Comment: yes, |x|<1. I think if $ \sum z(i) x^i $ does not converge neither will $ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=0}^{n} f(k_ih)h $ and then you have $ \infty =  \infty $. I don't understand your last question " Lastly how can you guarantee that latter sum is the sum of (finitely many) powers of x? " Can you rephrase it?  n can be $ \infty $ as well

Comment: Like, what if $J(x^r)=x^r/r!$? Do you know if even they can or can't happen? If it is, then $\sum_{r=1}^\infty J(x^r)=e^x$, and you can't write that as $\sum_{i=1}^n x^{k_i}$, so your definition doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, it should be $ \sum_{i=1}^\infty z(i)x^i $. I hope we can take the example $ e^x - 1 $ we notice $ k_i $ does not belong to the integers. So  $ J(x) = e^x $ is not allowed

Comment: By the way some none trivial examples are $ k_i = i $ then $ \sum_1^\infty z(r)/r = 1$ because $ z(i \neq 1 ) = 0 $ . Another example is $ z(r) = \mu(r) $ where $ \mu(r) $ is the Möbius function. Then $ n = 1 $ and the L.H.S reduces to $ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(h)h = 0 $. $ k_i $ can also be equal to the i'th prime but one would proabably need a computer to calculate it.